# css transition for scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use CSS to scroll through my page with a fixed nav bar , i want it to move through the nav links on the same page , i tried using the transition property, so maybe i need something else

```css
                 #Home{
         background-color: #f4f4f4;
         transition: 0.5s;
            }
```

```html
 <section id="Home">
</section>
<section id="About">
</section>
<section id="Services">
</section>
<section id="Contact">
</section>
```

Comment: are you mean 'position:fixed'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use javascript.

```
`$('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
}, 500, 'swing', function () {
      $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
});`
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/Dxtyu/141/)